# Определение расположение программы в памяти с помощью try/catch?

Tags: c++, linux, память, указатели

Перемещаю указатель в начало памяти `p = 0`, увеличиваю его, запоминаю (`noerr`) момент, в который не возникает ошибки. Затем ищу момент, когда снова появится ошибка (`err`). Получится, что программа находится в интервале `[noerr; err)` памяти. Но код крашится уже на первой итерации.

`Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)`

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char *p = 0, *noerr = 0, *err = 0;
  while (1) {
    try {
      char c = *p;
      if (!noerr) {
          noerr = p;
          cout << "noerr: " << (int)noerr << endl;
      }
    } catch (...) {
      p++;
      if (noerr) {
          err = p;
          cout << "err: " << (int)err << endl;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Почему `try/catch` не ловит ошубку? Как исправить программу, чтобы она работала как я задумал?

ОС: `Linux`.

**решение**

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main();

char *begin_ptr;

void find_begin() {
  char *p = (char*) main;
  while (1) {
    begin_ptr = p;
    char c = *(--p);
  }
}

void find_end() {
  char *p = (char*) main;
  while (1) {
    ofstream f("end.txt");
    f << (int) p;
    f.close();
    char c = *(++p);
  }
}

void sig_handler(int signo) {
  ofstream f("begin.txt");
  f << (int) begin_ptr;
  f.close();
  cout << "Signal " << signo << endl;
  cout << "begin_ptr: " << (int) begin_ptr << endl;
  cout << "dist from begin to main: " << ((char*)main - begin_ptr) << endl;
  find_end();
  exit(0);
}

void HandlerRun () {
  printf("Sig Handle Initialized!\n");
  signal(SIGSEGV, sig_handler);
  signal(SIGSTOP, sig_handler);
  signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);
  // signal(SIGKILL, sig_handler);
  signal(SIGABRT, sig_handler);
  signal(SIGINT , sig_handler);
}

int main() {
  HandlerRun();
  ofstream f("main.txt");
  f << (int) main;
  f.close();
  cout << "main: " << (int) main << endl;
  find_begin();
}
```

`main.sh`:

```
./main > /dev/null
beg=$(cat begin.txt)
end=$(cat end.txt)
echo begin: $beg
echo end: $end
echo end - begin: $(echo $end - $beg | bc)
```

Пример вывода:

```
begin: 134512640
end: 134529023
end - begin: 16383
```

Comment: никак. try/catch грубо говоря ловит только исключения С++, а обшибка доступа - signal (SEG-) от системы. Способы перехватить есть, но 2 попытку сделать не дадут.

Comment: и кстати читать можно почти откуда угодно, это писать нельзя. но это UB и гарантий никаких.

Comment: Как в моём случае поймать сигнал?

Comment: `void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    printf("G with %d signals",signo);
    exit(0);
}

 void HandlerRun
  () {
    printf("Sig Handle Initialized!");
    signal(SIGSEGV, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGSTOP, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGKILL, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGABRT, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGINT , sig_handler);
  }`

Comment: *чтобы она работала как я задумал?* -- а что задумал-то?

Comment: @PinkTux, найти начало и конец доступной памяти для программы.

Comment: А как это соотносится с тем, что написано в subj (*Определение расположение программы в памяти*)? И что значит "доступной", доступной для чего именно?

Comment: @PinkTux, под местом расположением программы я как раз и понимал то место в памяти, которое доступтно программе для чтения (и, возможно, записи).

Comment: Сегменты данных, что ли?

Comment: Возможно. Я без понятия как в `linux` программа располагается в памяти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Ваша программа имеет pid == PID, то подробнейшая карта памяти расположена в файле

```
/proc/PID/maps
```

Получить значение pid можно вызовом функции

```
PID = getpid();
```

Comment: Вместо получения значения PID можно заглянуть в `/proc/self/maps`